pyautogui/pywinauto/pynput not working for Device Manager Automation
I can open the device manager on windows using pyautogui, but when I want to press tab or any other key stroke with pyautogui , it doesn't work. Although it works fine for Microsoft Word etc. I've also tried with pynput/pywinauto but issue not resolved
import pyautogui

import time

import keyboard

pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'r') pyautogui.write("devmgmt.msc")

pyautogui.press("enter")

time.sleep(2)

pyautogui.press("tab")

pyautogui.press("↓")

I'm looking to press "tab" using pyautogui/pywinauto/pynput in device manager so that device manager is focused.

You have to run your script as Administrator for such system applications, because they always start in privileged mode even if Python is started as usual (non-privileged mode). Also for device driver installation/removal you may use devcon.exe utility from Microsoft which should be suitable for the most cases. More complicated cases may require learning setupapi.dll which I personally didn't done till the very end (only partially).
